# OverlayContainer with custom components and ShadowDom

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have some multiples components with ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom set (angular 15). This components will be web-components used by other shell app (angular 7). The problem is that OverlayContainer is not working correctly because it attach the 'cdk-overlay-container' element to body and not to the shadom-root element.

I created the following files in order to customize the OverlayContainer:

```
import { OverlayContainer } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { Platform } from '@angular/cdk/platform';

export class ShadowRootOverlayContainer extends OverlayContainer {
  constructor(
    document: any,
    _platform: Platform,

    private selector: string
  ) {
    super(document, _platform);
  }

  override _createContainer(): void {
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    container.classList.add('cdk-overlay-container');

    const customElement = document.querySelector(this.selector) as HTMLElement;
    customElement.shadowRoot?.appendChild(container);

    this._containerElement = container;
  }
}
```

```
import { OverlayContainer } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { Platform } from '@angular/cdk/platform';
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ShadowRootOverlayContainer } from './ShadowRootOverlayContainer';

@NgModule({})

export class ShadowRootOverlayModule {

  static forRoot(config: Config): ModuleWithProviders<ShadowRootOverlayModule>  {

    const module = {
      ngModule: ShadowRootOverlayModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: OverlayContainer,
          useClass: ShadowRootOverlayContainer,
          useFactory: (platform: Platform) => {
            return new ShadowRootOverlayContainer(window.document, platform, config.selector)
          }
        },
      ]
    };

    return module;
  }
}

interface Config {
  selector: string;
}
```

But when I import the ShadowRootOverlayModule in my component's module:

```
 ShadowRootOverlayModule.forRoot({ selector: name }),
```

It just create one instance and the value of this.selector of the first file is always the same, and just one component is working. How can I create multiple module instances in order to get the correct element for each component module?

Thanks in advance